# Reading a document's content from the gdata API?

Tags: gdata-api, google-data-api

I'm using the java library to access the gdata api. I just want to be able to print the contents of a document. I setup my project to list all the docs in my feed, now that I have a document listing, I want to print its contents:

```
for (DocumentListEntry entry : feed.getEntries()) {
    // Ok, how do we print the doc's contents now?
    entry.getContents();
}
```

It looks like we're supposed to get the URL from the entry, then read the contents at the URL ourselves. I found a post stating that this is how we get that URL:

```
MediaContent content = (MediaContent)entry.getContent(); 
String url = content.getUri();
```

but when I try to read from it, I get an html response saying 'this content has moved'. I read that this is because we have to authenticate our http-read method, but I'm not sure how to do that. Is there really no built-in way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi user246114 - Can you please let me know if you have found any solution of the problem? I am facing the same issue and couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, use this, it's wrapped up in these classes for you, thankfully:

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/java/sample/docs

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaContent content = (MediaContent) entry.getContent();
MediaSource source = docService.getMedia(content);
InputStream in = source.getInputStream();
```